# Cómo evitar que Angular2 limpie (Sanitize) mi variable

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Ocurre el siguiente problema, tengo una variable que almacena una imagen en base64 
para imagenes pequeños no hay problema

```
<img src="{{ imageBase64 }}">
```

El problema se da en imágenes de gran tamaño que al parecer el bueno de angular2 antes de renderizarla la intenta limpiar, pero al ser un string tan largo javascript lanza un error del tipo **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.[Symbol.match] (<anonymous>)
    at String.match (native)
    at sanitizeUrl (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:71639:44)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:71011:114)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas19.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/PreguntasRespuestas/component.ngfactory.js:2708:87)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas19.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas19.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50181:37)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas18.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/PreguntasRespuestas/component.ngfactory.js:4513:15)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas18.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas18.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50181:37)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas2.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/PreguntasRespuestas/component.ngfactory.js:5032:14)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas2.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at View_PreguntasRespuestas2.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50181:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_PreguntasRespuestas0.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/PreguntasRespuestas/component.ngfactory.js:5194:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49833:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Editor0.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/Editor/component.ngfactory.js:1265:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49833:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Editor_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/EditorModule/Editor/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50181:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Pages0.detectChangesInternal (/PagesModule/Pages/component.ngfactory.js:124:15)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49833:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Pages_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/PagesModule/Pages/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50181:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_App0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/App/component.ngfactory.js:77:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49833:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_App_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/App/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:49848:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50043:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:50836:20)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:41797:67
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ApplicationRef_.tick (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:41797:25)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:41716:105
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:15244:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54777:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:15243:34)
    at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:15137:43)
    at NgZone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54646:62)
    at Object.next (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:41716:81)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:47064:52)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:110450:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:110399:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:110352:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:110316:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:110068:25)
    at EventEmitter.emit (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:47050:76)
    at NgZone.checkStable (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54742:40)
    at NgZone.onLeave (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54818:14)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54780:27)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:15243:34)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://127.0.0.1:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:15151:47)
```

Comment: el string `imageBase64` llega a tu componente como un `@Input`?

Comment: no, es cargado por un input[type=file] y convertido a base64 mediante la clase FileReader que angular2 provee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De momento la unica forma indirecta de solucionarlo que encontre es la siguiente:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Resto del codigo omitido no viene al caso
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }


// Funcion de carga de la imagen que se activa al funcionar
private fileChangeListener($event) {
    let fileList: FileList = $event.target.files;
    this.imageBase64 = null;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onloadend = (loadEvent: any) => {
            this.imageBase64 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myReader.result);
            this.data.type = file.type;
            this.modalImagen.open();
        };
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Y para mostrarla cualquiera de las 2 alternativas me fue valida

```
<img src="{{ imageBase64 }}">
```

ó

```
<img [src]="imageBase64">
```

Que se resumen en usar **DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl** en ves de enviar la cadena en formato crudo, ahora estoy viendo como volver a la cadena original a la hora de subirlo pero eso es un problema menor, de momento solo creo una variable duplicada sin convertir mientras uso la primera para mostrar, uso la segunda a la hora de enviar los datos al servidor.

Comment: Puedes usar ese mismo codigo para hacerlo una pipe y sea reusable ...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, deberia funcionar:

```
<img [src]="imageBase64">
```

Comment: Funciona con imágenes pequeñas o de tamaño moderado con imágenes de gran tamaño lanza un error de recursividad al intentar limpiar la cadena tan larga.